# Format string attack, convert output to readable format in bash

Tags: c, bash, printf, exploit

I'm working on a ctf challenge. This is the relevant code section,

```
void details(){    
    char name[100];
    printf("Please enter your name: ");
    scanf("%100s", name);
    printf("Hello %s!\n", name);    
}
```

If I EOF scanf/stdin, printf will output arbitrary data, which I
hope to put to some use but it's indiscernable hex data in bash.

I tried piping the output to hexdump or od -t x1, redirect to a
file but whatever I'm trying the shell output doesn't match what
I'm seeing in gdb, e.g. 0xf7facce0 0xf7e7b6e3 etc etc.

[output/bash](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cIE9a.jpg)

Any pointers?
Thanks.

Ok, I'll eloborate, bear with me the interface here is still somewhat of a challenge all by itself.
I was trying to keep my question generic to avoid running into any spoilers.
There's are other attack vectors I'm looking at, this is just one of the them.
And I know I can overflow the buffer but that will only get halfway where I
need to go.

```
void welcome(){
    char name[100];
    printf("enter you name : ");
    scanf("%100s", name);
    printf("Welcome %s!\n", name);
}

int main(){
    printf("Toddler's Secure Login System 1.0 beta.\n");

    welcome();
    login();

    // something after login...
    printf("Now I can safely trust you that you have credential :)\n");
    return 0;   
}
```

In gdb it looks something like this,

[gdb](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OqPeE.png)

At the top you can see the printf output when I quit scanf with Ctrl-D, "Welcome &%%/%/&", obviously it's non readable in this format. In the disassembly the buffer is at $ebp-0x70, 0xffffd068 and following. As you can see there's a few words before the first 0 byte and I was hoping to be able to make these available
in bash. Now, if I pipe the program's output to od to convert to hex, all I get to see is printable ASCII codes in hex, where did the non-printable characters go?

[pipe to od -t x1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2RhtU.png)

Comment: It's unclear what your question it, can you clarify? (make it more precise)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! If you consider hex data to be "indiscernable", then you probably shouldn't be looking into what happens when a program invokes undefined behavior in the first place... what do you expect to use that "data" *for*? -- `hexdump` is a good first step, but that screenshot you posted is not the output of `hexdump`.

Comment: `scanf("%100s", name);` can lead to a buffer overflow as the null-terminator could be written out of bounds of the array `name`. Use `%99s` instead to prevent it.

Comment: format needs to be %99s since the null character is always added

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I think the point here is to find a way to exploit this snippet, e.g. by overwriting the functions return address. But I'm not exactly sure...

Comment: He's intentionally using `name` uninitialized. I think a potential buffer overflow is the least of his problems at that point. :-)

Comment: Hmm... By using the uninitialized array `name` you need a lot of luck to go beyond the end of the array and into the stack where you could add exploits. The chance of there being *no* zero byte in the array is rather small.

Comment: I don't consider hex data to be indiscernable per se but the way it's presented to me in bash isn't very useful (see screenshot). I expect the printf output to be stack data, or pointing me to the stdin buffer in memory which I can use in a different section of the program.

Comment: You could pipe the output to a [hex-dump program](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/hexdump.1.html), if you want to see the hexadecimal data. But as mentioned, if there's a zero-byte (which is the string null-terminator) in the array, the `printf` will not go beyond that, which means you might not go outside of the array and therefore not see the actual stack data (like return address etc.)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude at this point I'm looking in all direction, it doesn't have to be stack data to be useful to me The data that I found in gdb, and which I hope to be able to show in bash seems to be pointing to the stdin buffer? The hex section starts with 0xfbad2022 and the next three dwords reflect what ever I read in scanf.

Comment: All in all, I don't think teaching "how to exploit" is on-topic here... or it shouldn't be. Your program has UB, all bets are off, and that is that IMHO.

Comment: @DevSolar its one of the challenges at pwnable.kr (the passcode one). I'm avoiding spoilers that why I'm trying to keep it generic but I do realize my terminology might be a bit off. It's been a while since I've been looking into developing exploits.

Answer (score 1):

The real function of interest in this challenge is `login()`. To give you a hint on this challenge without spoiling it for you: remember that even when the `welcome()` function ends and the stack is cleared, those values can still remain in those memory locations. Look at the `scanf()` function in `login()` instead.

Comment: Thanks Shane. I've been trying for a week now to use the overlap of name and passcode1 to inject an executable address within login into passcode1, and then use the subsequent scanf/%d to place a relative short jump opcode at that address to jump directly to the system call but if I use the full 100 chars it will just skip the scanf call. But cheers for keeping me motivated, already (re)learned a great deal in the last couple of days.

Comment: No problem, I found this challenge much trickier than some of the others in the Toddler's Bundle. If you want any hints just let me know.

Comment: Sorry mom.. I got confused about scanf usage :( Wow..that was quite something :)